# autofac with signalr no parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, autofac, signalr-hub

I'm using autofac on my current Asp project and everything works fine until i decided to use dependancy injection in a signalR Hub

here's my startup class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        //builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<DiscussionHub>();
        // Repositories
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(LanguagesRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        // Services
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(LanguageService).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        var config = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container)
        };
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr",config);
    }
}
```

and here's my Hub

```
public class DiscussionHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IDiscussionService _discussionService;
    public DiscussionHub(IDiscussionService discussionService)
    {
        _discussionService = discussionService;
    }}
```

the error is that i'm getting no parameterless constructor on my Hub? any suggestion ?!

Comment: Where do you register your `IDiscussionService` with the container builder?

Comment: I've updated my code you can check it

Comment: Try simply resolving: IDiscussionService after your container is created. You might expect to have registered a service for IDiscussionService when you called: RegisterAssemblyTypes but the problem might be there.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/autofac/issues/416

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use properties? And have `PropertiesAutowired()`? Still I don't see where you register `IDiscussionService`.

Comment: You can have a look at a [repo that uses SignalR and Autofac here.](https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-dependency-injection-autofac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should register your hub `ExternallyOwned` it should manage lifetimescope by itself. That's mean autofac will not disposed them.

Second, everything will be resolved from root container in your hub. That's mean `Per Dependency` or `Per LifeTimeScope` will live with your hub(forever with app). So you should manage lifetime in your hub.

Even if we manage life time in your hub, `Per Request` will not be supported. Because of this, when we create new lifetimescope, we will create it with `AutofacWebRequest` tag. That way, we can resolve your `Per Request` instance. But pay attention this instance will be totaly **different** with other instance in normal request lifetimescope.

Your Hub should be like this:

```
public class DiscussionHub  : Hub
{
  private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;
  private readonly IDiscussionService  _discussionService;

  public MyHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
  {
    // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.
    _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");

    // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.
    _discussionService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IDiscussionService>();
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    // Dipose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.
    if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)
    {
      _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

Your register should be like this:

```
  .
  .
  builder.RegisterType<DiscussionHub>().ExternallyOwned();
  var container = builder.Build();
  GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new   Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
  .
  .
```

Owin Integration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // STANDARD SIGNALR SETUP:

    // Get your HubConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
    // rather than using GlobalHost.
    var config = new HubConfiguration();

    // Register your SignalR hubs.
    builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    var container = builder.Build();
    config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

    // OWIN SIGNALR SETUP:

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the standard SignalR middleware.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
  }
```

Check more [detail](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html).